# Why does alias in /etc/bash.bashrc not apply to sudo?

Tags: command-line, sudo, root, bashrc, alias

I've added the line

```
alias ll='ls -l'
```

to the `/etc/bash.bashrc`. After a restart, the alias `ll` from that file affects me, which I checked by commenting out the corresponding alias in my `~/.bashrc` (and logging out and back in after that edit). However, it seems to not affect `root`, as when I type `sudo ll`, I get "*no such command*". Shouldn't the alias work in any situation if it's in the system-wide .bashrc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo` will ignore any aliased commands from `.bashrc`.

You can work around this by creating an alias for sudo too --> `alias sudo='sudo '`

You need the space after `sudo`, since `man` tells us:

```
If the last character of the alias value is a blank, then the next command word following the alias is also checked for alias expansion.
```

Comment: Did you get this from the manpage for alias? Cause I don't have a manual entry for that.

Comment: @StefanHamcke no - for bash

Comment: What, in God's name, does that man quote mean?  Does it refer to (a) the next command word in bash.bashrc; or (b) the next command word entered on the command line?  What if nothing follows, in either case?  If a subsequent command word is found, what happens (a) if it is expanded; and (b) if it is not expanded, and why?  What is the next command word in this case?  How and why does evaluating the next word for alias expansion have any effect on the evaluation of the first word, and why would it then cause root to observe configuration?

Comment: Why, also, does sudo, or root, resist configuration in this way, and where is that documented?

Comment: @ebsf have a thorough read of [the full section on aliases](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases), that should answer most of your questions. As to `sudo` "resisting" configuration, `sudo` itself doesn't know or care about bash's configuration, and nor should it. Why should utility X care about utility Y's configuration at all?

Comment: @muru, thanks, but of course, I wouldn't have posted if I hadn't.  It's illiterate and reflects poorly on every individual and organization associated with it.  Otherwise, it's root that's resisting configuration.  Root is a user, not a utility, and it should care about the bash configuration if it is going to execute commands in it.