# bash.bashrc alias fail: Why?

Tags: bash, sudo, root, bashrc

This is a permutation of the question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718249/why-does-alias-in-etc-bash-bashrc-not-apply-to-sudo).

This question differs in that (a) it relates to commands entered as root in a terminal as opposed to commands entered as a non-root user by invoking sudo before the alias; (b) root observes some aliases in this case while ignoring others; (c) the solution in the other question fails here; and (d) the answer to the other question is impenetrable and so fails even in that instance.

The question is, I've added these two lines to the bottom of `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```
alias ls='ls -la'
alias ping='ping -c 4'
```

When in a terminal session as root, *i.e.*, after having done:

```
sudo -s
```

The first `alias` fails and the second succeeds.  This is the case regardless of whether the solution proposed in the other question, *i.e.*, adding

```
alias sudo='sudo '
```

to `/etc/bash.bash`, has been done.

The answer to the other question states:

> sudo will ignore any aliased commands from .bashrc.

This is false in this case, as already noted.  Furthermore, why `sudo` would resist configuration in this way is not explained, nor is any documentation referenced for this behavior.

So, how does one get root to observe all, instead of just some, aliases specified in `/etc/bash.bashrc`?

Comment: The files you're altering are not used during `bash` startup. Read `man bash` about "Startup files". Also read `man sudo sudoers`. `sudo` has its own rules.  `sudo` was written to be a  replacement (it's better in many ways) for the obsolete `su` command.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just that the first alias gets overwritten by something like `alias ls='ls --color=auto'` from roots own .bashrc (`/root/.bashrc`)?

Comment: "sudo will ignore any aliased commands from .bashrc." That's for commands run by `sudo`, e.g, when you do `sudo ls` or `sudo ping`. Commands run in a shell started by `sudo` (e.g., `sudo -s` and then run `ls` in that shell) are obviously not run by `sudo`, so this doesn't apply.

Comment: @waltinator, it's rather astonishing to say that bash.bashrc is not used during bash startup, don't you think?  Isn't that its entire purpose?

Comment: @steeldriver, that actually may be it.  I'll have to check but I'm too busy filing bug reports on 22.04.  The Server installer doesn't even boot, if you can believe that.